# NameError: uninitialized constant Plaqueorder::ShrineImageUploader when using Shrine 2.8 on Rails 5.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, shrine

I cannot get [Shrine](http://shrinerb.com/) to work no matter what I do and I am using the simplest of setups to start with.

**db/schema.rb**

```
create_table "plaqueorders", force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
    t.text "image_data"
    ...
```

**initializers/shrine.rb**

```
require 'shrine'
require 'shrine/storage/file_system'

Shrine.storages = {
cache: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new('public', prefix: 'uploads/cache'),
store: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new('public', prefix: 'uploads/store'),
}

Shrine.plugin :activerecord
Shrine.plugin :cached_attachment_data # for forms
```

**uploaders/image_uploader.rb**

```
class ShrineImageUploader < Shrine
end
```

**models/plaqueorder.rb**

```
class Plaqueorder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :plaque_type, presence: true
  include ShrineImageUploader[:image]
end
```

Comment: Welp, to start with, it seems `image_uploader.rb` defines `ShrineImageUploader`. I would think the file would be named `shrine_image_uploader.rb` or the class would be named `ImageUploader`. Otherwise, you have a naming mismatch.

Comment: well, my face is red... been staring at this all morning and the obvious was right in front of me :)

Comment: Happens to the best. I added as an answer in case you would like to upvote/approve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, to start with, it seems `image_uploader.rb` defines `ShrineImageUploader`. I would think the file would be named `shrine_image_uploader.rb` or the class would be named `ImageUploader`.

Otherwise, you have a naming mismatch.